# Rails remember form details without ActiveRecord / ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my forms, users are displayed a specific view in a sequence depending on a value in a session. This is all working great except when users go back to a previous form, the form is not pre-filled with data from the session.

My model does not extend ActiveModel as I am not using local DB's for anything.

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <%= field_set_tag do %>
        <label for="form_firstname">First name:</label>
        <%= text_field "form", "firstname" %>

        <label for="form_surname">Surname:</label>
        <%= text_field "form", "surname" %>

        <label for="form_dob_3i">Date of Birth:</label>
        <%= date_select("form", "dob", :start_year => 1912, :end_year => 1994, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :prompt => { :day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year' }) %>

        # and many other fields including radio/check/text/select ...

        # next / back buttons...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My question is how can I get the form to remember data from the session and pre-populate the field?

For text fields, I can add a value attribute like so, but I am not sure this is the best way to go about it:

```
<label for="form_address_line_1">Address:</label>
<%= text_field "form", "address_line_1", :value => session[:quote]['policyholder']['address_line_1'] %>
```

I am also not sure how to apply this to radio fields etc as the following would not work (although it makes sense to me):

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'form[homeowner]', 'yes', :checked => 'checked' if session[:quote]['policyholder']['homeowner'] = 'yes' %>
<label for="form_homeowner_yes">Yes</label>

<%= radio_button_tag 'form[homeowner]', 'no', :checked => 'checked' if session[:quote]['policyholder']['homeowner'] = 'no' %>
<label for="form_homeowner_no">no</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your back button in your view to render the previous form and not redirect to it...
so try this rather than redirect_to: `render 'your_controller_action'`